# Eclipse project .classpath can delete/change manually?

Tags: java, eclipse

Eclipse created `.classpath` for all the project in work-space. It can be any bad effect if we delete it or manually change ? In my project it have a entry like this

```
<classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-client/3.0.8.Final/resteasy-client-3.0.8.Final.jar" sourcepath="M2_REPO/org/jboss/resteasy/resteasy-client/3.0.1.Final/resteasy-client-3.0.1.Final-sources.jar"/>
```

and manually i changed with some other version because i am using some new version but its referring old version. Will it make my project unstable or undeployble ?

Comment: Project properties -> Java Build Path -> remove all `M2_REPO/*`, add Maven Dependencies.

Comment: It will recreate .classpath entries?

Comment: What do you mean by *recreate*?

Comment: Regenrate the entries or file.

Comment: Still not clear. Bottom line: in java build path libraries you should have single maven deps as a library, not all jars in M2_REPO.

Comment: Did  M2_REPO relates with .classpath entries ?

Comment: Yes i am using Maven only

Answer (score 2):

Use the Project 'Properties > Java Build Path' to alter the `.classpath` file.

Deleting this file will loose all your class path settings.

Comment: Any one to recreate it ? remove the project and reimport?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what BAD means to you. If you delete it eclipse wont know about source folders and dependencies. Your project structure will be lost. If project is configured with maven, it can restructured with 
`mvn eclipse:eclipse` 
command.

You can edit it if you know what are you doing.

Comment: `mvn eclipse:eclipse` will recreate it everytime when i will run this command then if i will delete it it would recreate?

Answer (score 0):

Its config file for Eclipse. The best is change config throught eclipse UI. But no problem if you change this file, while the change has well structured and well data.

Best regards.

Comment: If its Config file Why it is referring to old jar which i am not mentioned anywhere

Comment: You can remove that particular line if you sure you no longer need it.